# Javascript regular expression match and get

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this in javascript:

```
'nearly 2 pound/12345'
```

and i need to check if this string match the pattern like

```
'some string useless/number'
```

and get the number.

I have created a regex `/\/\d+/g` to get the number,but it will also get the char '/'.

so How can i solve these?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some effort before posting questions on SO, people won't usually just solve everything for you :)

Comment: You should post the regexps you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expression is simply "forward-slash followed by numbers", this should suffice

```
let numbers = (/\/(\d+)/.exec(str) || []).pop()
```

To break it down...

1. Create a regex for a forward-slash followed by one-or-more digits (that you want to capture)

   ```
   let regex = /\/(\d+)/
   ```

   You may want / need to tweak this to make it more specific. Say for example that the numbers always appear at the end of the string, you would use `/\/(\d+)$/`.
2. [Execute the regex against your string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). This will either return `null` for no match or an array with the entire match at index 0 and your capture group at index 1, eg `["/12345", "12345]`

   ```
   regex.exec(str)
   ```
3. Create an expression for that results in an array, even if no match is made

   ```
   let arr = (regex.exec(str) || [])
   ```
4. Use `Array.prototype.pop` to get the last array entry

   ```
   let numbers = arr.pop()
   ```

`numbers` will be undefined if there was no match.

Comment: Thanks,this work for me.Bur what's the difference between `/\/\d+/g` and `/\/(\d+)/`?

Comment: The `g` flag sets the regex to "global" mode; it will continue searching the string even after finding a match.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
var position = input.lastIndexOf("/");
var number = input.substr(position+1);
```

It simply finds the last "/" in the string and then stores everything after it in a variable called number.